# File not reading properly C++ ifstream

Tags: c++

I have an application where I'm using ifstream to read the file. 
I have 1000 numbers in the file in each line. My application should read all these lines.

But when I have the number of lines less than 800 it is showing the count as 0
why is it like this. 
The code is below.

```
int tmp, count=0,ucount=0; 

ifstream fin("rnum.txt");
while(fin >> tmp)
{
    count++;
}
cout<<"showing count: "<<count<<endl;
ucount=count;
fin.open("rnum.txt");
int i=0;
cout<<"Before entering loop"<<count<<endl;
while(fin >> tmp){
    iArray[i++]=tmp;
}
```

When I read a file with 1000 lines it is only reading 720 lines too. I don't understand why its reading like this.

Is there anything wrong in the code.

My requirement is to take the number of lines COUNT to the ucount variable.

Comment: Maybe some lines in the file are not numbers? Then it would stop the loop early. Please show an _example_ of the file, especially the lines around where it stops (not the complete file).

Comment: Well in terms of "wrong" I'd say it's wrong to read the file twice.  Read it once.  In terms of the error, I would suspect it's something in the input file itself that is causing the problem.

Comment: For the first part : you did not open the file before counting the lines.

Comment: @georgesl Check the `fin` declaration again.

Comment: By the way, you need to close the file before trying to open it again. Or seeking to the beginning of the file instead of closing/reopen the file. Or do the counting _and_ input at the same time.

Comment: count is not the number of lines. it's the number of integers read...

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of lines in the file use `getline` function.

```
#include<string>

std::string line;
while (std::getline(fin, line))
{
    ++count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve your error, as I believe that is related to the input file itself, however reading the file once will at least make it quicker:

```
vector<int> iArray;
int tmp; 

ifstream fin("rnum.txt");
while (fin >> tmp)
{
    iArray.push_back(tmp);
}
cout << "showing count: " << iArray.size() << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file with `fin.close()` before opening the file for the second time or leave the file open, reset the read pointer and clear the eof flag.

Answer (score 0):

If the Input is improper (if a char instead of digit is encountered), the >> operation fails and `fin >> tmp` return false thereby breaking the loop prematurely.

moreover You should close the file before reopening it. And I beleive the functionality You needed/wanted was merely `fin.seekg(0)`.

Besides your code can be simplified to :

```
int temp;
ifstream fin("rnum.txt");
vector<int> iArray;
while(fin >> tmp)
{
    iArray.push_back(tmp);
}

std::cout << "showing count : " << iArray.size();
```

As suggested by @trojanfoe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058205/6459731